# How to split and rearrange list

Tags: r

I have list of year_month dataframes.
They are like this
`List = c(  A2017_1, A2017_2,....A2017_12, A2018_1, ... A2018_12, ..... )` and so on.

I want to rearrange this list with the months, like this:

```
 month_1 = c(A2017_1, A2018_1, A2019_1, ....)
 month_2 = c(A2017_2, A2018_2, A2019_2, ....)
.
.
```

... and so on.

This is what I tried.

```
for (x in 1:12){
LF <- emp_yymm[grep(str_c('+_', x,'$'), names(emp_yymm))]
LFF <-append(LFF, as.list(LF))
names(LFF)[x]<- str_c('mon_',x)
}
```

And it failed.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make sure your example uses valid R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really start with some reproducible example, but below is the solution I'm giving assuming some things about your data.

```
 name <- paste0("A",rep(c("2017","2018","2019","2020"), each = 12), "_",rep(1:12, 4))
 L <- vector("list",48)
 names(L) <- name

 Final <- vector("list",0)
 for(x in 1:12){
   indx <- grep(pattern = paste0("_",x,"$"), x = names(L)) #find index of things ending in _num
   ord <- order(names(L)[indx]) #correct order
   tmp <- L[indx[ord]] # make list subset
   Final <- c(Final,tmp) # build list
 }
```

I'm assuming that the element names of the list are the Year_month values and you are just trying to reorder the list. If you are trying to make 12 more lists per month you can dynamically name variables with the `assign` function...

Building a list as I have isn't always best. It is usually better to specify the final length first.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (x in 1:12){
  LF <- emp_yymm[grep(str_c('+_', x,'$'), names(emp_yymm))]
  if(x<10){
  assign(str_c('mon_0',x),LF)
  }
  else{
    assign(str_c('mon_',x),LF)
  }

}

monlist<-mget(ls(pattern="mon_\\d+"))
```

Comment: Generally code only answers aren't particularly useful. You should explain how this code solves the problem.